# Why would my cross validation accuracy be noticeably lower than my actual testing accuracy?

Tags: cross-validation, accuracy

I coded up a nested cross validation scheme for model selection, feature selection, and hyper parameter optimization. Here are some results I got:

Model selection accuracies (for the two models I tested): 0.65 0.66

Model hyperparameter loop accuracies (for testing the hyperparameters of the winning model): 0.65 0.62 0.63 0.62

Final Model accuracy: 0.721519

The final model accuracy is higher than the cross validation results. Usually this is a good thing, but the difference seems a little too large for comfort. Assuming I coded this correctly, I can only attribute lower accuracy to a smaller sample size in the cv phase (FYI: I used a .8 split for any train and test split including the inner and outer nested validation splits).

Is there anything that comes to mind for why else this might happen?

Comment: What is your sample size?

Comment: ~800. this is then split into train/test or validation by a .8/.2 ratio at each nesting step

Comment: I think that with "just" ~800 samples CV is a bit too restrictive (especially given that we are not talking about repeated-CV), I do not think you will get very reliable estimates to begin with. I would strongly suggest using bootstrap in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Some back-of-the-envelope ideas:

- First thought is always a quick glance at uncertainty due to number of tested cases:
  with n = 800 and observed accuracy .721519, the 95 % confidence interval is ca. 69 - 75 %, and
  for n = 640 and observecd accuracy .63, the 95 % confidence interval is ca. 59 - 67 %.
  Not overlapping, but also not *that* far apart. In practice, random error may be larger if the models are not totally stable.
- Second thought: some popular choices of how to actually select the optimal model are biased towards too complex models, i.e. do systematically overfit. Thus, generalization error may be lower than optimal. OTOH, a popular version of how to obtain the final model is to take the *hyperparameters found in the optimization* and use them for fitting on the larger (outer cross validation) training data (as opposed to running another optimization on the larger training set and take *those* hyperparameters). This may counteract to a certain extent the overfitting inside the optimization, which *could* lead to better models. In other words, you may be lucky in having a sweet spot where overfitting and underfitting roughly cancel out each other.

---

(I'd formulate choice of model, features and model hyperparameters all as a single hyperparameter optimization problem, thus 1 nesting level)